# How do I rearrange the list of render layers?

Tags: render-layers

This may seem like a strange question but I set up a space scene with stars and planets and etc and each had their own layer except the planets which I accidentally put on the same one as the stars. I create a layer for the planets but it's on the bottom of the stack and I'm not sure if it affects it, so here is my question:

How do I take the bottom layer and put it on the top?

[image: Property of CraftyMaelyss]

Also due to copyright reasons I can't upload the file. Sorry guys :(

Comment: imho it is not affecting anything... it all depends on the later usage in compositor/nodes. anyway I can't find how to reorder them...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Render layer order doesn't actually effect the render (aside from maybe changing the order in which the layers are rendered).

However, for organisational purposes it can be nice to reorder them. For this reason I created a script, available on Github, which adds up and down arrows to reorder the render layers:

https://github.com/RayMairlot/Move-Render-Layers

**Note:** Untested in the latest version of blender, not guaranteed to work, save before using etc.

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you so much! :D